# advice choosing a networking framework for java

Tags: java, network-programming

**Short version:** Need advice(pros/cons) on choosing a java networking framework for a client/server application with low number of users/requests and relatively big amount of data.

Possible options:

1. RMI
2. Apache River
3. Netty (this seems more asynchronous oriented, can it do synchronous calls?)
4. Some other framework that will make my life easier? :)

**Long version:** The current project I work on is a desktop application written in java that allows the user to optimize a part of the supply chain. Note that the application, up until now, was desktop only. It had a database installed on the local machine and that was it. Now we have new requirements to change the code to support a shared/network database. Installing a database on a network server and firing up several instances of the application revealed (as expected) a lot of problems. The biggest problems come from the fact that the database interaction was not developed with concurrency in mind. We have a lot of lock waiting and several deadlocks occurring. A decision was taken that the data access layer will be modified to account for the new requirements.

It seems that it will not be possible to write a DAL to allow for concurrent access without separating the application in a client and a server which will handle data access and possibly some business logic. We don't need a very high performance solution, there aren't that many messages, but the problem lies in the amount of data.

A typical usage scenario looks like this:

1. Start the application
2. Import data from a CSV file (usually between 600MB-1GB) and store it for future use
3. Add scenario configurations (very small amount of data) and store them
4. Fire up the optimization (takes the data from step 1, applies the configuration, applies some optimizations/restrictions)
5. Display the optimization result.

Step 4 will be done on the server, steps 1-3 and 5 will be executed on the client.

Do you guys have an suggestions/advice?
Thanks.

Comment: I understand that the problem is that you have a 600Mb - 1GB file on local machine and need to upload it to the server. Am I right?

Comment: @PiotrGwiazda Yes, basically you are right. The file is imported on the local machine, it is converted to a data format that is used by the application and should be stored to the database for use during step 4. Also at step 3, the simple configuration changes (change the value of a double field, add some entity to a list) should be stored too.

Answer (score 0):

So the real question is how to upload large amount of data. 
For such soluton I'd not go to RMI - it's too restricted. 
Apache River seems like some kind of invention. 
Netty is a low level networking framework. You'd be forced to write your own protocol.

I'd just use simple HTTP server and upload data with HTTP POST request. You can work with Gzip compression. HTTP is quite good with large files.

On a server side any servlet container would probably do (Tomcat, Jetty etc).

On a client side [Apache HTTP Components](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) should be enough. You may also try [Ning Async HTTP Client](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client).

Comment: What about RMI is 'too restricted'? I know RMI is not perfect and depending on your use case, it's might not be the right tool for the job, but 'too restricted'?

Comment: Also, it should be noted that if you use HTTP, you'd have to do some kind of session handling, as it is a stateless protocol.

Comment: By saying that RMI is too restricted I meant that introduces very tight coupling between modules. You need to have exacly the same Java classes in the same versions for all API, DTOs and Exceptions for Java serialization to work. You'd need to keep that in sync on desktop clients. The update procedure may be hard. You'd not need HTTP session if it's just a single HTTP POST. You'd need to keep session accross HTTP requests.

Comment: Well, the coupling is basically there, no matter which protocol you use. Coupling means that a change on one side forces a change on the other side. You have to keep everything "in sync" anyway. The benefits of RMI are exactly what you list: you get all compile time _and_ runtime type checks Java offers "for free" and you don't have to deal with marshalling/unmarshalling your objects. And for sending files or other large data streams, there is [RMIIO](http://openhms.sourceforge.net/rmiio/), which integrates very well.

Comment: You don't need HTTP sessions if you are just doing stateless communication, that's true. But depending on what the OP exactly meant by steps 4 and 5, you might need to keep track of which data belongs to which client on the server.

Comment: It should be quite easy to handle HTTP sessions with any servlet container and even HTTP client. Apache HttpClient handles cookies automatically. Any JAX-RS client should also do. You'll still need some kind of basic authentication mechanism. There are plenty of it for HTTP.

Comment: @SimonLehmann thanks for the link, it might just make RMI a good option for me.